# Google Apps Script Text rotation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found in the UI of Google Spreadsheet the functionality Text Rotation but i found no equal function in google apps script.

So how can i rotate Text with Google apps script?

Regards

Edit: I created a Spreadsheet with the needed rotation as default setting after this a make a copy of this spreadsheet.

Comment: currently there is no method to rotate text under [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Ok, this means there is currently noway to rotate text with google apps script?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old ask but incase others are interested...This can be done now.  Just add .setTextRotation() to any range selected and it will rotate the text to the desired degree. For example:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(1,1).setTextRotation(-45);
```

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setTextRotation(Integer)

Answer (score 3):

You may follow the formula given in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/KdyxPSBGjjI/IOlavPF4tIAJ). Here's a sample code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  cell.setValue('=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE((MID($B2, ROW(INDIRECT("YY1:YY"&LEN($B2))), 1)&CHAR(10))))');
}
```

In this example, we'll set the value of B2 in A1 in vertical format. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, it is a good idea but is there a way to change the direction? It is really awkward that google has this function not in google apps script.