# Can you rotate text in google sheets using google script?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I cannot find any functions to rotate text in google sheets using google script.  Does anyone know of any script workarounds?

Comment: Agree, George, original poster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to see [this post from help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/KdyxPSBGjjI/IOlavPF4tIAJ).

Here is a sample code snippet:

> ```
> function myFunction() {
>   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
>   var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1);
>   cell.setValue('=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE((MID($B2, ROW(INDIRECT("YY1:YY"&LEN($B2))), 1)&CHAR(10))))');
> }
> ```

Referenced from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275753/google-apps-script-text-rotation).

Comment: Thanks, but I am after a way to mimic the text rotation that Google introduced for users (as referenced in your first link). It may be something Google have introduced for users but forgotten to set up the API.